# QTCreator Not Building (Windows x64, MinGW)

Tags: c++, qt, qt4, mingw, qt-creator

I'm having a problem when I try building an application with QTCreater.

This is the error I get:

QT Compile Output:

```
12:40:01: Running steps for project untitled2...
12:40:01: Starting: "C:\Qt\4.8.5\bin\qmake.exe" C:\Users\user\Desktop\untitled2\untitled2.pro -r -spec win32-g++ "CONFIG+=declarative_debug"
12:40:01: The process "C:\Qt\4.8.5\bin\qmake.exe" exited normally.
12:40:01: Starting: "C:\MinGW-back\bin\mingw32-make.exe" 
C:/MinGW-back/bin/mingw32-make -f Makefile.Debug
mingw32-make[1]: Entering directory `C:/Users/user/Desktop/build-untitled2-Unnamed-Debug'
c:\Qt\4.8.5\bin\uic.exe ..\untitled2\mainwindow.ui -o ui_mainwindow.h
g++ -c -pipe -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\untitled2" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\main.o ..\untitled2\main.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\untitled2" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\mainwindow.o ..\untitled2\mainwindow.cpp
C:\Qt\4.8.5\bin\moc.exe -DUNICODE -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\untitled2" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\mkspecs\win32-g++" -D__GNUC__ -DWIN32 ..\untitled2\mainwindow.h -o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -c -pipe -g -frtti -fexceptions -mthreads -Wall -Wextra -DUNICODE -DQT_DLL -DQT_GUI_LIB -DQT_CORE_LIB -DQT_HAVE_MMX -DQT_HAVE_3DNOW -DQT_HAVE_SSE -DQT_HAVE_MMXEXT -DQT_HAVE_SSE2 -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_NEEDS_QMAIN -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtCore" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\QtGui" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include" -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\include\ActiveQt" -I"debug" -I"." -I"..\untitled2" -I"." -I"..\..\..\..\Qt\4.8.5\mkspecs\win32-g++" -o debug\moc_mainwindow.o debug\moc_mainwindow.cpp
g++ -mthreads -Wl,-subsystem,windows -o debug\untitled2.exe debug/main.o debug/mainwindow.o debug/moc_mainwindow.o  -L"c:\Qt\4.8.5\lib" -lmingw32 -lqtmaind -lQtGuid4 -lQtCored4 
c:\Qt\4.8.5\lib/libqtmaind.a(qtmain_win.o): In function `WinMain@16':
c:\iwmake\build_mingw_opensource\src\winmain/qtmain_win.cpp:93: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
c:\iwmake\build_mingw_opensource\src\winmain/qtmain_win.cpp:135: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
c:\Qt\4.8.5\lib/libqtmaind.a(qtmain_win.o): In function `ZN7QVectorIPcE7reallocEii':
c:\iwmake\build_mingw_opensource\src\winmain/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h:512: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
c:\iwmake\build_mingw_opensource\src\winmain/../../include/QtCore/../../src/corelib/tools/qvector.h:513: undefined reference to `_Unwind_Resume'
c:\Qt\4.8.5\lib/libqtmaind.a(qtmain_win.o):qtmain_win.cpp:(.eh_frame+0x12): undefined reference to `__gxx_personality_v0'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
mingw32-make[1]: *** [debug\untitled2.exe] Error 1
mingw32-make[1]: Leaving directory `C:/Users/user/Desktop/build-untitled2-Unnamed-Debug'
mingw32-make: *** [debug] Error 2
12:40:07: The process "C:\MinGW-back\bin\mingw32-make.exe" exited with code 2.
Error while building/deploying project untitled2 (kit: Unnamed)
When executing step 'Make'
12:40:07: Elapsed time: 00:07.
```

I am using QT 4.8.5 that I downloaded from [Qt libraries 4.8.5 for Windows (minGW 4.4, 317 MB)](http://download.qt-project.org/official_releases/qt/4.8/4.8.5/qt-win-opensource-4.8.5-mingw.exe)

and I am using MinGW that I got from installing Codeblocks MinGW

Please help. Its such a pain setting up QTCreator for Windows.

**EDIT:**
The solution was to use MinGW 4.4, which I found here: https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4D8x6CJEmtuczdiQklwMEs4RUU/edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must use the MinGW-w64 toolchain shipped with Qt to link to the Qt libraries. Or rebuild Qt yourself with your toolchain, which for 4.8 isn't such a pain as it is for 5.x.

The ABI is different between the compiler versions you're linking, and there is no way to make these compatible.

Comment: Ok, so how do I go about doing this? I have qtcreator-3.0.1 installed and Qt 4.8.5 libraries installed. Where do I get and install MiniGW-w64 for QT?

Comment: @Leo: somewhere in the Qt Creator install directory is a "mingw" folder. Just set your Qt Creator "Toolchain" (under settings: Build&Run" to point to the "g++.exe" in that directory and you should be set. Be sure to rebuild everything.

Comment: Thanks, I managed to get it working - Unfortunately, I could not find a minGW folder in my Qt directory, I had to download v4.4 from https://docs.google.com/file/d/0B4D8x6CJEmtuczdiQklwMEs4RUU/edit

Thanks! Its working now.

Comment: @Leo Ah yes, it seems the Qt libraries do not come with their GCC. Just for reference, you need a "dw2" GCC build, preferably version 4.4, but later versions might work as well.